# Exponential matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $$\displaystyle (\lambda_1 - x)^{b_1} \cdots (\lambda_h - x)^{b_h}$$

Using Jordan theory, show $e^B$ (the exponential matrix's) characteristic pol. is $$\displaystyle (e^{\lambda_1} - x)^{b_1} \cdots (e^{\lambda_h} - x)^{b_h}$$

I tried to do this for an hour or so, and I got absolutely nowhere. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of $e^B$ then?

Comment: Hint: What is the first statement telling you about the matrix B? Once you understand this, how does it help you with Jordan to write out the matrix exponential. Try a 2x2 example if that is not clear.

Comment: This is what it tells me...  
 trace(e^J) = b_1(e^λ_1) + ... + b_h(e^λ_h) = trace(e^B). Beyond that I'd need a better hint, because I'm stuck.

Comment: Write a matrix from the perspective of eigenvalues. What does B look like to have that characteristic polynomial? Write out the 2x2 and 3x3 case. Clear?

Comment: I don't see how that helps me! I'm just really confused right now can you elaborate more

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Calculations or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Diagonalizable_case

Comment: I got that the characteristic polynomial of e^J is (e^λ1−x)b1⋯(e^λh−x)bh. I don't see much else there that will help me. Could you just be more specific? I know how to do the number examples, and I've been stuck on this a while.

Comment: The characteristic polynomials between e^J and e^B are supposed to be the same, and that's the answer?

Comment: Because I thought that like 10 minutes into the problem, but it wasn't proven anywhere in my notes so I kept trying other things. Can you let me know if I'm on the right track?

Comment: Yeah, I think I got it. That was pretty easy, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any Jordan theory, just that any matrix is conjugate (over $\mathbf C$) to a triangular matrix. For a triangular matrix, taking a power amounts, on the diagonal only, to taking that power of the diagonal entries, so (passing to the limit) the same goes for exponentials as well. Now use that the characteristic polynimial of a triangular matrix is $\prod_{i=1}^n(X-a_{i,i})$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B$ is in Jordan block form. Then $B=\Lambda+T$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$, and $T$ is strictly upper triangular. Then  $$\det(\lambda I-B) = \det(\lambda I -\Lambda) = \prod_k(\lambda-\lambda_k)$$

It is straightforward to show that $B^k = \Lambda^k + T_k$, where $T_k$ is strictly upper triangular. Since $$e^B = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} B^k$$ it should be clear that $$e^B = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} \Lambda^k+T_* = e^\Lambda + T_*$$ where $T_*$ is strictly upper triangular. Since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, $e^\Lambda$ is diagonal with entries $e^{\lambda_1},...,e^{\lambda_n}$

Hence $$\det(\lambda I-e^B) = \det(\lambda I-e^\Lambda) = \prod_k(\lambda-e^{\lambda_k})$$